# Finding empirical formula

Tags: stoichiometry

When determining the formula of a compound, why do we divide by the smallest number of moles once we already have calculated the number of moles for each element in order to find the empirical formua of a given compound?

Comment: Because we don't like to have too many decimal fractions hanging around.

Answer (score 2):

The empirical formula is the **simplest** positive integer ratio of the atoms that are  present. Thus, by dividing by the smallest number, we obtain the **simplest** whole number ratio of atoms.